# Web gui for reporting services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Have a project where were building custom business reports accessible via web browser. As we run SQL server I would like to use reporting services instead of writing custom reports in my application. 
Is there a way to publish a GUI for generating reports from reporting services on the web, or is there any convenient way to get the reporting services available in a browser?

Thanks
Tomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the report viewer control which can be used on the web.  There is a download for it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=cc96c246-61e5-4d9e-bb5f-416d75a1b9ef&displaylang=en)

Comment: It actually isn't too shabby.  It will display the report and offers the ability to export it in a number of formats including excel.